# Doctrine criteria on subclasses of abstract entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I have an abstract entity which is inherited by two subclasses. I'm using it in association with other entity and now I want to create criteria to filter out objects with the property set to some value.

My superclass:

```
/**
 * @ORM\MappedSuperclass
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\Bar\AddressRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType(value="SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discriminator_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"homeaddress" = "HomeAddress", "companyaddress" = "CompanyAddress"})
 */
abstract class AbstractAddress
{
    /**
     * @var bool
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", options={"default": 0})
     */
    protected $active;
}
```

Subclasses:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\Bar\AddressRepository")
 */
class HomeAddress extends AbstractAddress
{

}
```

---

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\Bar\AddressRepository")
 */
class CompanyAddress extends AbstractAddress
{

}
```

Entity with association:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Foo\Bar\CustomerRepository")
 */
class Customer
{

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Foo\Bar\AbstractAddress", cascade={"all"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $addresses;

    /**
     * @return Collection|null
     */
    public function getAddresses(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->addresses->matching(
            Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('active', true))
        );
    }
}
```

This setup produces exception:

> ResultSetMapping builder does not currently support your inheritance scheme.

The problem is that it tries to instantiate `AbstractAddress` instead of one of the subclasses respectively.

Is there any way to achieve this filtering using `Criteria` API?

I know that I can use `filter()` instead, but this function doesn't impact SQL query, so I would rather have this solved used criteria.

Comment: What is the purpose of having this two subclasses extending from the parent? could you elaborate? maybe what you're asking is not the solution

Comment: @ReynierPM I made up example above and unfortunately I need several separate subclasses as each of them has some unique properties.